# How to stop a new node being added to DOM using Chrome/Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, dom-events, mutation-observers

I am writing an extension to detect some malicious behavior of some scripts. These scripts add some nodes into the DOM after page gets loaded. I am able to get these nodes using

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", checkContents, false);
```

But how can I stop them from being loaded? Can this be done in Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Use MutationObserver with childList and subtree.

```
var grid = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('newtab-grid');
var mobs = new iframe.contentWindow.MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type, mutation);
        if (mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
            var link = mutation.target.querySelector('.newtab-link');
            if (link) {
                link.setAttribute('target', '_parent');
                console.log('set target on this el')
            } else {
                console.log('this ell has no link BUT it was an added el')
            }
        }
    });
});
mobs.observe(grid, {
    childList: !0,
    subtree: !0
});
```

now this will tell you when its addingNodes and it gives you what was added in `mutation.addedNodes`. you can iterate throuh that and remove what was added. I'm not sure if you can prevent it from adding, but you can definitely remove it after it was added.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver#MutationObserverInit